# Asp .Net method in controller taking a list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to send a list of strings to a method in a controller in asp net mvc. How can I do this?

I want my method in my controller to look something like this:

```
public ActionResult CutFile(string[] filenames, string target)
```

Optionally I can change the string array parameter to something like this:

```
public ActionResult CutFile(IEnumerable<string> filenames, string target)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the data in this format:

```
<input type="text" name="filenames[0]" value="A"/>
<input type="text" name="filenames[1]" value="B"/>
<input type="text" name="filenames[2]" value="C"/>

<input type="text" name="target" />
```

Comment: what if I am using jquery with ajax to do a post to the method, how would I do that?

Comment: just pass a list of string: 
{filenames: ['A','B','C'], target: 'X'}